# How to include remote jar dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

I need to include a third party jar to my pom.xml (using Maven 3.2.5 on a Linux environment).

If the jar file is available on the same machine that runs the build I can just declare the dependency in this way:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
        <version>Foo-1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/myspace/javalibs/foo-1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But what if the jar is on a different server such as

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>myrepo</id>
            <url>http://192.168.0.14/download/java/thirdparty_repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

In what element should I specify the name of the jar file?

Comment: is the server a `maven-server`?

Comment: Start using a repository manager and deploy this jar their and change to usual dependencies without scope system.

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi It's not a maven-server.

Comment: @khmarbaise So, the answer to my question is that in the pom.xml it's not possible to specify a jar file name that is not located on the build system. Correct?

Comment: You can but it does not make sense cause it will make your build environment depent which is in general not a good idea.

Comment: So, if I can, where should I specify the filename?

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>/myspace/javalibs/foo-1.0.jar</systemPath>
```

from pom and Maven will find the jar in http://192.168.0.14/download/java/maven_repo automatically

Comment: This doesn't work for me as I don't have a Maven server running on that server.