# Is there a way to include a public jar URL as a maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a jar file which I have publicly hosted on s3. I would like to include it in another Maven Java project.

Can I include it in the pom.xml as a dependency?

Comment: It is better to put in mvnrepository like an open source project so that it will be visible to everyone. Other option is to maintain Nexus in Amazon S3 and publish the jar file so that it can be used in other project.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750417/how-to-include-remote-jar-dependency-in-maven) and its comments? Maybe it helps (TL;DR better put it in a repo)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I did take a look at that link. The question is  kind of the same but the answer does not help as it did not help the original author either

Comment: @Sambit can you share an example URL on how to do the nexus in s3?

Comment: Check this links, https://guides.sonatype.com/repo3/quick-start-guides/aws-for-repo/ , https://blog.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-3.12-support-for-s3-blob-stores

Comment: I recently answered somewhat similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478250/2168752

Answer (score 1):

If you file structure follows the maven folder structure then you just need to specify

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>example-repo</id>
            <url>https://your_website/path</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

If you want to just link the jar then you need to use a download plugin https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin to download your jar to a lib folder

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-jbpm</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wget</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://path_to_your_jar</url>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

then reference it with

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you also give sample for the <dependency></dependency>?

Comment: Actually all I have is a jar file. It does not follow maven folder structure.

Comment: Then you probably need a download plugin like: https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin then you can use the code provided by Qingfei Yuan below to add a dependency to a local jar

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```